# MATLAB indexing for a matrix

Tags: matlab, indexing

If `T` is a `3x3` matrix.. what does `T(1:2,3) = k` mean?

I *think* `T(1:2)` means the first 2 columns. So does `T(1:2,3)` mean the first two columns in the last row..?

Comment: Please read [the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#f1-85544) before posting on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning the value k to the first two rows of column 3.